# SwiftUI TextEditor overlay ignores allowsHitTesting

Tags: swiftui

I use a Text as a placeholder label on top of a `TextEditor`. No matter how I add it, via `ZStack` or `.overlay`, it cancels the touch of the `TextEditor`. So when I click on the Text/Placeholder, the TextEditor doesn't become active, if I tap around it, it does. This is reproducible in the following example view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .padding()

            Text("blabla")
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this `UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear` inside your view's initializer (or better inside main App initializer) and then, instead of use ZStack or overlay to add a placeholder on the top of a `TextEditor`, you can use the background modifier like this: `.background(Text("Placeholder..."))`

Comment: Thanks, that's a valid workaround. I ended up setting my placeholder on the actual TextEditor with reduced opacity and a tap gesture recognizer which deletes that text and resets opacity to 1.